# Where to get well designed and coded applications written in C# to learn from them?

Tags: .net

I got into log4net code and Nunit. Both of them gave me something to think about and taught me something new. What other aps do you know, with source code open that worth reading their code? Also, what is the best way to get into the code, sure if you can't ask its creator a question?

A little addition: I'd like to have sources read by you and recommended in a way I read this, it is really cool and worth reading, worth digging into the code. Sure it is very helpful to know about codeplex, codeproject and other sites where you can get some code to dig into, but the question is about what do you recommend

Comment: Have you found that source code is the best way for you to learn? Have you tried beginner's books, or videos? These are at least intended to teach, whereas the log4net code was intended to be log4net.

Comment: Yes, I found it usefull and much a better way as I read a lot of books already. I like to learn by reading books, but think that code digging is other way. It`s learning math by reading pure theory or by solving the problems. I think you can`t be a good mathematician if you never solved a taugh problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might also want to check out [Scott Hanselman's weekly source code discussions.](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CategoryView.aspx?category=Source+Code)

Instead of just blocks of code he takes time to discuss it in detail.

Answer (score 3):

Take a peek at Wikipedia's [List of Free Software Programmed in C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Free_software_programmed_in_C_Sharp) which I am sure will hold some gems. The MonoDevelop IDE and programs like F-Spot, I have used, and are of high quality.

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but free != open source.

Comment: @esteban, be pedantic ... the distinction is necessary

Answer (score 3):

Do you know you can look at the .net source code. Also, you can [debug it](http://blogs.msdn.com/sburke/archive/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code.aspx). You can learn a lot from it.

Ask the [reflector genie](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) and it will allow you to see source of most .net apps .

Comment: Yes, I know it. But I`m looking for well designed apps, not for the way to look inside any .net app.

Answer (score 1):

Try http://www.codeplex.com/. In my opinion, the best way to get into the code is to download it, run it locally (if possible) and debug through it, by stepping along the code. Refactoring also helps you to understand the code more deeply since you have to reason about it for doing it successfully.

Comment: codeplex is a great site as codeproject but I`d like to know what worth reading them, that have good design and implementation. Unfortunately lot of project from codeplex are not very well written and not worth considering them as best practices.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Spring.NET](http://www.springframework.net/).  That's some well-thought out, well-designed code in C#.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to study framework code, obviously the Microsoft framework is relevant. You can look at most of details using Reflector.

Also, the [C5 Generic Collection Library](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/) is worth a look.